# Best way to convert list of defauldict(list) into dataframe

Tags: python

I was wondering if there's a faster way to convert multiple defaultdicts into a pandas dataframe.This is my code so far for what i wanted to do. But it's super slow for large datasets so i was wondering if there's a faster way.

```
list_df = []    
for i in range(0,len(data['2subset'])):
            df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['2subset'][i],orient='index').transpose()
            list_df.append(df)
        result = pd.concat(list_df, axis=1, join='inner')
```

ex. data

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'2subset': [defaultdict(list,
                          {'Sampling': ['f',
                            None,
                            's',
                            '3',
                            '0',
                            '0',]},
                            {'Sampling': ['f',
                            None,
                            's',
                            '3',
                            '0',
                            '0',]},
                            etc.....]}
```

ideal dataframe would be the key and it's list of value in a column
i.e column 'sampling' along with it's list of values as the rows in that column

Comment: Are you looking for simply `pandas.DataFrame(data["2subset"])`? If not, I think we will need to see a working example of your data and the results you hope to get from that data.

Comment: Note: your current example data is not valid python even if the `etc....` is removed